# Hypothesis Test: Difference Between Means

Tags: time-series, hypothesis-testing, t-test, mean

[image]I would like to know if I can use a t-test to verify the following hypothesis for the two groups in the chart above: μ1 - μ2 > 0. I am not sure if this test can be used on time series.

Tks!

Comment: Statistical tests for differences in mortality ratios will depend primarily on the numbers of events in the two groups. Unfortunately you cannot derive those features from summarized data like this. To use a t-test on those numerical values you would need to assume that they were a)Normally distributed and b) had roughly equal variances. Both of those assumptions are clearly violated here.

Comment: Do you have the sample sizes?

Comment: One more assumption for @DWin's list is (c) independence, almost surely lacking in time-series data.

Comment: may i know that the population from which data has been taken is normal or not. If the data has been taken taken form two independent normal populations and sample is small you can apply hypothesis test for diffrence of means.

Comment: @BruceET: indeed. In fact any test designed for time-series investigations would surely find substantial evidence of autocorrelation in this data as well.